# Maximum Cache Size with Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-chrome, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working in an app that needs to have loads of data available even offline.

In the documentation, it says the default cache size for Firestore is 40MB but we can set it to unlimited.

[image: Documentation]

My question is: If I set the cache unlimited, and I'm in Chrome, What's the maximum amount of data I can have offline? How many MB do I have? Is it limited by session, browser?

I've checked [Web.Dev](https://web.dev/storage-for-the-web/) and it says it (Chrome) can storage up to 80% of total disk space, Does this limit apply for CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED too with Firestore?

[image: WebDev Docs]

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore will observe the limits of the host browser.  It obviously can't exceed them (as the browser would not permit it - the Firestore SDK doesn't have any super powers), but it also won't place additional limits on itself if you configure it as such.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the response Doug. 

Based on what you said, my best guess would be "80% of the total disk space" based on the web.dev documentation. Right?

Comment: Sure, whatever the host browser limits are will be enforced by all code that attempts to write data locally.

Comment: @DougStevenson Can we check current cache size?